# How to find a string from a text file and load its line content

Tags: vb6

I am new to VB6 programming. I am trying to load a line from the whole text file that contains the string that I want.

```
1 abc
2 def
4 ghi
5 klm
6 opq
```

If my word to find is 'klm', I want the whole line '5 klm' in my string. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the filename in a variable sFileName:

```
Dim iFile as Integer
Dim sLine as String, sNewText as string

iFile = FreeFile

Open "C:\Folder\replacewithpath\db.txt" For Input As #iFile
Do While Not EOF(iFile)
  Line Input #iFile, sLine
  If sLine Like "*klm*" Then
   'sLine has got the line , use 
  End If
Loop
Close
```

Comment: sorry 4 my beginner question,how or where to load my db.txt ?

Comment: Thannnnk you ! I got it . :D

Comment: Open "EAT\db.txt" For Input As #iFile
    Do While Not EOF(iFile)
      Line Input #iFile, sLine
      If sLine Like "*853822DCEE4C6B59D4A9F0C4CDAF97989E29C83A*" Then
        MsgBox sLine
        
       
      End If
    Loop
    Close

How to braek when i got this line. coz msgbox repeatedly show that line. help me again please :D .